# Having two using static directives that has property with same name

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have pre C#6 code that code like this:

```
Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
string value = string.Empty;
```

I wanted to start using `using static` directive and change it to something like

```
using static System.Guid;
using static System.String;
// ...
Guid guid = Empty;
string value = Empty;
```

But this simply ends up with two errors

> Error CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Guid.Empty' and 'string.Empty'

Why can't compiler decide with `Empty` I want to use?

Comment: `var guid = Empty;` now put yourself into compiler's position :)

Comment: @Selman Genç yes `var` would not know which to use. But if I specify `Guid` or `string`? Why not?

Comment: `var` is a whole different story. When you use var the type is taken from the right side of expression (this is why you can't do just `var a;` - it will not compile) if it is known and not result of dynamic operation. But in your case it is not the type but class that has to be infered by compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not how the C# compiler is designed. Trying to guess what you mean looks simple in simple cases like what you have shown, but becomes problematic in other cases.

For example:

```
var value = Empty;
string s = Empty.ToString();
F(Empty.SomeMethod());
```

Comment: Well, it would make sence in simple cases. And for cases where it's really not clear which one you want - error still would be expected.